# Append Form text field value alone in the url

Tags: rest

I am trying to create a sample Online shopping application using SPRING+REST. I have a 1000 of products and I would like to make use of @RequestMapping("watches/{id}") annotation . But i dont know how to send the id form field value alone while submitting a form in jsp.

I want something like this

www.example.com/watches/1001

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have some jsp page which consists of all watches. This web page can be access by `localhost:8080/watches` URL.

If user click on any watches, user will land to `localhost:8080/watches/{watch-id}` page as the click on watch will redirect the request.

If your JSP is form based page, then user need to enter the watch-id ( or watch name which we need to map to watch id) and click on submit button will redirect the request to `localhost:8080/watches/{watch-id}`. Please let me know if you are ok with this.